# How to call vertex groups in Animation nodes [SOLVED]

Tags: animation-nodes, vertex-groups, instances, transform-orientation

I would orient some instances by vertex normals, but i'd like to control orientation by vertex groups, to give z negative values to some instances, like in the pictures.is it possible? i've tried with Vertex Group Input but it gives me unexpected results.

[image]

[image]
[image: Solved and added a Combine Vector to control also Guides parameter]
Solved by 3DSinghVFX, then i've added a Combine Vector to control also Guides parameter from Vertex Group Input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can achieve that effect by controlling the scale of the normals with the vertex weight.

1. First, instanced an object *(Cone)* on the vertex locations of the base object *(Cube)* using this node-tree:
   [image]
2. Then, remap the weight (using Vertex Weight Input node) which is in range (0, 1) to (1, -1) using Map Range node with the Threshold (in Threshold node) = 0.5 i.e., vertices which have weight less than 0.5 will have normals with scale = 1 (+ve direction) and vertices which have weight equal or greater than 0.5 will have normals with scale = -1 (-ve direction).
   [image]

You can very the Threshold as you like.

Blend File:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, great! you are the man :) , there are also some other ways to call a group of selected vertex to give them parameters? maybe i need to create a new question on StackExchange?

Comment: Vertex Group Node gives the weight of all the vertices or vertices specified by indices. For selected vertex: you first assign a weight to the selected vertices then later you can filter them using Vertex Group Node and Mask List node. If you want to know in more details then please create a new question.

Comment: Thanks, i posted a similar question linked, because i'm trying to orient instances in more complex meshes than a cube:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158093/animation-nodes-instances-orientation-in-a-dodecahedron

Comment: Please accept the answer of this question if you satisfy. I'll try to answer that question.

Comment: Ok, i did not know 'till now that one has to accept the answers. Thanks, done!